# Displaying report parameters in textboxes

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am getting an error when attempting to display report parameters in a textbox.
I have constructed an expression like:

```
="My Report for " & Parameters!ReportMonth.Value & " " & Parameters!ReportYear.Value
```

`ReportMonth` and `ReportYear` are string values

The error I am getting is:

> The Value expression for the textrun ‘Title.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’
>   contains an error: [BC30654] 'Return' statement in a Function, Get, or
>   Operator must return a value.

Note: `Title` is the name of the textbox object

I am using `SSRS 2008`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: How are ReportMonth and ReportYear defined?

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer.  I was using single quotes (') for the string literals in my expression.  Only double-quotes (") are allowed to delimit string literals.

Answer (score 0):

For those who wanted to try a different thing. I adding expression and it worked.